# Java servlet- Best way to get post requests body

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, post

I'm getting a post request- with a XML in the body.
what is the best way to get the requests body?

cheers:)

Comment: i don't want to use JSON- i want the most simple way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`request.getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream%28%29) to get the body as an `InputStream`, and parse this stream with an XML parser.